# Only duplicated an object, but on attempt to change its own texture, it simultaneously affects the texture of the object I sourced it from

Tags: texturing

On an object, I pressed Shift + D and then G, Y, and moved the newly spawned object away from the remaining original.  Got two identical looking objects now.

Problem:  When I go to edit the alpha on the duplicate, the setting affects both of them at the same time, like entanglement.  I just want my setting change on one object to affect only that object.

Can anyone help?  Thanks.

Comment: Materials are not made unique on copying by default. You seem to be editing material settings which would still be the same material as the original

Comment: ok thanks.  new question is above since I can only post once every 40 minutes

Comment: Why did you change the content of your question? If you have a different question post it separately

Comment: Never do that. Now all comments and possible answers will become invalid and totally unrelated to the post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you duplicate an object you are not creating a new material.
Both objects share the same one.

You need to assing a new material to the copied objcect.

To the right of the material's name you will see a number, it indicates how many ojbects are sharing a material (in this case 2). If you click on the number you will create a copy of the material and assign it to the object.

Changing the material now will result in no changes on other objects.

[image]